# I want implement purity measure in python

Tags: python, excel

I want implement purity measure in python, I have an excel file like this:
[image]

The numbers are cluster of laptops. I want to get the number of laptops per cluster like this:
[image]

can you help me??

Comment: Did you try *counting*? It's a very powerful algorithm. You begin at 0 and then always increment by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your excel file, concatenate your two columns before analysis with python.  If your data is in columns A and B in excel, you can concatenate with this formula:

```
=Concatenate(A1,", ",B1)
```

Here is the result:

[image: Concatenated columns]

Now that you have each brand combined with its cluster number, you can run a simple python script to count how many times each string appears.

Pseudocode for python:

```
d = dict()

For each row in concatenated column:
    If string in d: #checking if dictionary key already exists for this computer-cluster combo
        d[string] += 1 #add 1 if exists already
    else:
        d[string] = 1 #create key and assign value of 1 if key does not exist already

print(d)
```